# How can I debug Binary batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, debug, binary-files

I have a .bat file in binary format.
But I don't know its functioning.
How can I view the content in detail or debug the binary .bat file, or convert it to exe file?

Comment: How do you know it's a batch file?

Comment: When you open the file in Notepad, what are the first 10 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers of batch scripts just encode the script inside an `.exe`.

This means that to execute the script, they need to extract it
into a temporary folder and execute it from there, then delete it when
it's finished.

If your script is like that, execute it and kill it after it started
but before it's finished. Then search for its `.bat` file, whose name
might have been mangled.

Normally the script will be found in the Windows temporary folders.
Examine the folders in the environment variables TEMP and TMP,
for both System and User, to check if the script is there.
They will be found in *Start > Edit the system environment variables*.
The file could be the most recent `.bat` file in the folder.

If the batch compiler was not too tricky, this should find the script
in question.